# Emacs unable to find fonts?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, emacs

I compiled emacs from source on Ubuntu 11.10 and unfortunately, it only seems able to find the default X monospace font. How do I connect emacs with the system fonts?

Answer (score 1):

I installed libxft, libfreetype, libgtk,libm17n and recompiled emacs. This linked things up!